# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-migrations

I have the script below, which gives me an error: 
"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PlanShiftAssignments_dbo.User_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "SWS", table "dbo.User", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated."

As you can see, in WHERE clause I check if UserId exists in dbo.User. What are the other possible reasons of the error?

**UPDATED:** I am also want to know what row from select statement causes the error. Any advices on debugging this query will be appreciated. I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlanShiftAssignments] (
    [PlanShiftId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.PlanShiftAssignments] PRIMARY KEY ([PlanShiftId])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_PlanShiftId] ON [dbo].[PlanShiftAssignments]([PlanShiftId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_UserId] ON [dbo].[PlanShiftAssignments]([UserId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlanShiftAssignments] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.PlanShiftAssignments_dbo.PlanShifts_PlanShiftId] FOREIGN KEY ([PlanShiftId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PlanShifts] ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlanShiftAssignments] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.PlanShiftAssignments_dbo.User_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
insert into dbo.PlanShiftAssignments
                    select ps.Id as PlanShiftId, ISNULL(ps.AssigneeId, psi.UserId) as UserId, ISNULL(psi.[Status], 1) as [Status] from dbo.PlanShifts ps
                    left join 
                    dbo.PlanShiftInvitations psi
                    on ps.Id = psi.PlanShiftId
                    where (psi.UserId is not null and psi.UserId IN (select Id from dbo.[User])) 
                    or (ps.AssigneeId is not null and ps.AssigneeId IN (select Id from dbo.[User]))
```

Comment: To debug you can execute the `select` without the `where` clause and add columns for the various conditions, e.g. `case when psi.UserId IN (select Id from dbo.[User]) then 1 else 0 end as UserIdInUsers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you **always** include the target's column list on each `INSERT` statement.

```
insert into dbo.PlanShiftAssignments (
    PlanShiftId,
    UserId,
    Status)
SELECT
    ps.Id as PlanShiftId, 
    ISNULL(ps.AssigneeId, psi.UserId) as UserId, 
    ISNULL(psi.[Status], 1) as [Status]
...
```

Your table is created with the order `PlanShiftId, Status, UserId` and the column order from your current `SELECT` is `PlanShiftId, UserId, Status`, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You have a strange data model, if `UserId` and `AssigneeId` do not already refer to `User` in the underlying tables.

In any case, your `where` clause is

```
where (psi.UserId is not null and psi.UserId IN (select Id from dbo.[User])) or
      (ps.AssigneeId is not null and ps.AssigneeId IN (select Id from dbo.[User]))
```

This leaves open the possibility that `psi.UserId` matches but `ps.AssigneeId` does not.

To ensure that the logic matches, use the same expression as in the `select`:

```
where coalesce(ps.AssigneeId, psi.UserId) in (select Id from dbo.[User])
```

Comment: @KirillLudcev . . . In that case, I don't think it is the foreign key constraint that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be for the fact you've specified an OR in your WHERE clause, therefore either the AssigneeId or UserId is in the User table but not the other and therefore invalidates the FK constraint.